# How to prove that $\log a = \log b \Rightarrow a=b$ without assuming that its true?

Tags: logarithmic-scale

Why is $\log a = \log b \Rightarrow a=b$  true?

Comment: This "answer" does not answer the question and should be a comment.

Comment: @will Is this a question abou math or about the Mathematica software?

Answer (score 2):

Straightforward approaches are

```
FindInstance[Exists[{a, b}, Log[a] == Log[b] && a != b], {a, b}, Complexes]
*({})*
```

and

```
FunctionInjective[Log[z], z, Complexes]
(*True)*
```

Answer (score 2):

`Reduce` can do it:

```
Reduce[Log[a] == Log[b], {a, b}]
(* b == a *)
```

Comment: Or `Reduce[Log[a] == Log[b], b] // FullSimplify`. Simply `Reduce[Log[a] == Log[b]]` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Simple proof

```
Exp /@ (Log[a] == Log[b])
(* a == b *)
```

Of course the converse is not true

```
Log /@ (Exp[a] == Exp[b])
(* Log[E^a] == Log[E^b] *)
```

Comment: This demonstration only holds because $x\to e^x$ is known to be injective on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @A.G. as Mathematica knows